# \u0092 is not printed in UILabel

Tags: ios, objective-c, unicode, uilabel

I have a local json file with some descriptions of an app and I have found a weird behaviour when parsing `\u0092` and `\u0091` characters.

When json file contains these characters, the corresponding parsed `NSString` is printed like "?" and in `UIlabel` it dissapears completely.

Example "L\u2019H\u00e9r."  is showed as "LHér." instead of "L'Hér."

If I replace this characters with `\u2019`, then I can see the caracter ' in `UILabel`

Does anybody any clue about this?

EDIT: For the moment I will substitute both of them with character \u2019, it is also a ' and there is no problem confusing it with a control character. Thank you all!

Comment: Your Json file is probably not in UTF8 format. In terminal use 'od' to get the actual bytes and make sure those code points are proper UTF8, and that the file itself is not UTF16 encoded (it would have a 2 byte header at the start). When loading the file use the NSUTF8.... Decode option too. If you still cannot resolve it please add the actual hex byte values for that string to your question.

Comment: The example does not contain `\u0091` or `\0092`, and these characters are control codes (control characters), so they should not be expected to have a graphic presentation.

Comment: It sounds like the real problem is that the data is in windows-1252 encoding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer is a little speculative, but I hope it gets you on the right tracks.

Your best bet may be to give up and substitute `\u0091` and `\u0092` for something else as a preprocessing step before string display. These are control characters and are unprintable in most encodings. But:

If rest of the file is proper UTF, your json file probably has problems: encoding is wrong ([CP-1250](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1250)?) while you read the file as UTF, some error has been made when converting the file, or a similar issue. So another solution is of course fixing your file.

If you're not sure about how your file is encoded, it may simply be encoded in CP-1250 - so reading the file using `NSWindowsCP1250StringEncoding` might fix your problem.

BTW, if you hardcode a string `@"\u0091"`, you'll get a compilation time *error* `Universal character name refers to a control character`. Yes, not even a warning, it's that much unprintable in Unicode ;)

Comment: It was Windows-latin-1 indeed. But yes, I have open the file forcing to read as Windows-latin-1 and then I saved it using UTF-8. Thanks!